# How do you compare $\chi_{red}^2$ values?

Tags: chi-squared-test

I've got two models of velocity curves fitting a Low Surface Brightness (LSB) galaxy: one is MOND-like, the other ΛCDM.  I've fit them both with Chi-Square minimization.  I understand the winning model is the closest to 1, but I'm unsure of the exact method to test 'closeness'.  Is it simply the numerical difference?  For example, if I have a model fit with an $\chi_{red}^2$ of 1.4 and another with a fit of 0.5, does the first model win? (|1.4 - 1| = 0.4 vs. |1.0 - 0.5| = 0.5)

Comment: Given that most readers here will be unfamiliar with the definition of reduced chi-squared, as well as precisely how you're calculating it (and its sensitivity to stated error variance), you should probably briefly explain it for the benefit of the 99% of readers here who don't realize that what you're asking about is somewhat different from the ordinary chi-squared they're used to seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand.  In general, the model with lower $\chi^{2}$ is preferred.  However, if one model uses more parameters than another, then perhaps the smaller $\chi^{2}$ is just due to overfitting.  Criteria such as AIC and BIC have been developed to help with this.

Comment: It's easy to get a $\chi^2_{red}$ == 0 if the error variance is overstated, so I'm confused why a value of 0 is better than a value of 1.