Using ANOVA for model comparison with a different ratio, how does it differ?
When we compare two models with ANOVA then we typically compute an F-score like
$$F = \frac{\left(\frac{RSS_1-RSS_2}{p_2-p_1}\right)}{\left(\frac{RSS_2}{n-p_2}\right)}$$
where subscripts refer to the models, $p_1<p_2$ are the number of model parameters, and $RSS$ is the computed sum of the squared residuals.
We could alternatively use different comparisons like
$$F' = \frac{\left(\frac{RSS_1}{n-p_1}\right)}{\left(\frac{RSS_2}{n-p_2}\right)}$$
How do these approaches differ?

Related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579260/ and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181103/

I see now that they have a one-to-one relationship. So inference should be the same.

The two statistics $F$ and $F'$ have a one to one relationship
$$F'(n-p_1) -F (p_2-p_1)=  \frac{RSS_1}{\left(\frac{RSS_2}{n-p_2}\right)} - \frac{RSS_1-RSS_2}{\left(\frac{RSS_2}{n-p_2}\right)}
= n- p_2$$
